# How to add XML layout to custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have a custom view like this:

[image]

```
class SquareView : View {

    private lateinit var mRectanglePaint: Paint


    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
        init(null)
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        init(attrs)
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context?,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
        init(attrs)
    }

    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?) {

        mRectanglePaint = Paint().apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            color = Color.RED
        }

    }


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.apply {
            drawRectangle(this)
        }
    }

    private fun drawRectangle(canvas: Canvas) {
        val rect = Rect()
        rect.left = 100
        rect.right = rect.left + 100
        rect.top = 100
        rect.bottom = rect.top + 100

        canvas.drawRect(rect, mRectanglePaint)
    }

}
```

And, this is my blue_square.xml file:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blue_square"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to add this XML layout to my view and set position to bottom of the red square.

I added this code but this time only the blue square appears.

```
val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blue_square, this, true)
```

I want to include the blue square in my custom view and change its position.

How can I do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can think of 2 approaches to this problem, the question is how complicated and big is the real xml layout will you want to add to your view and do you want to add multiple xml layouts?

Comment: No I want to add a single XML layout. In XML, there is only one LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I said 2 different approaches, so the first is in a bit more detail but I'll also outline the others.

1)The first is to inflate and layout the xml to a `Bitmap` and then draw that Bitmap to you `Canvas` in the right place.

Inflate your xml BUT don't attach it or parent it to your custom view (as that really replaces you custom view (second and third parameters of inflate)

e.g.

```
val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
val xmlView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blue_square, null, false)
```

Draw this new view to Bitmap

Sorry this is Java but you can convert it to Kotlin as you seem to be using that.

```
Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(xmlView.getWidth(), xmlView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
xmlView.draw(bitmapCanvas);
```

Then in your `onDraw` draw this Bitmap to your canvas in the right position (setting `top` and `left` location to be below your red square)

Something like

```
plainPaint = Paint().apply { isAntiAlias = true }
canvas.drawBitmap (bitmap, left, top, plainPaint)
```

Note this is not exactly tested but it is similar to something I do a lot.

2)Don't invert the normal hierarchy of Views and ViewGroups, don't make your `SquareView` custom View be the single view your an App draws. Your `SquareView` custom view should just draw a view big enough to be the square (You should implement `onMeasure` for your custom view).

Then an App could do in it's xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SquareView
        android:id="@+id/custom_square"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blue_square"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```